# Order of references; references from appendix appear first in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, appendix

I have a "Master" file where I include all my chapters that consists of

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman,british]{babel}
\usepackage{./tex/mystyle}

\begin{document}
\input{./tex/titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\include{./tex/introduction}
\include{./tex/simulation}
\include{./tex/results}
\bibliography{./tex/bibliography}
\include{./tex/appendices}
\end{document}
```

In the "mystyle" file I use

```
\ProvidesPackage{./tex/mystyle}
\usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
```

and I am using Bibtex.
I thought the easiest way to format my appendix is just having my appendix as a normal chapter without using any fancy appendix package and manipulating the label of it manually so it is labelled as 'A' and sections as 'A.1', 'A.2', etc.
My appendices file starts with

```
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\chapter{Appendices}
\section{Mathematical Treatments}
\subsection{Equations of motions for a charged particle in an accelerating potential~\citep{Demtroeder2008, Hoffmann2007}}
Two hypothetical infinite flat surfaces separated by a distance $d$ and with the electric potentials bla bla bla
```

As one can see, the two references Demtroeder2008 and Hoffmann2007 now appear at the start of the references, which is a bit annoying because my actual first reference is now reference three. What do I need to do so that the references are actually in the order how they appear in the whole report?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsc` bibliography style doesn't sort entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. Instead, they are listed in the order citation call-outs are encountered in the document. There are two reasons why the `Demtroeder2008` and `Hoffmann2007` entries show up first in the bibliography even though the citation call-outs don't happen until the appendix chapter are

- the citation command occurs inside the argument of a `\subsection` directive:

  ```
  \subsection{Equations of motions for a charged particle in 
  an accelerating potential~\citep{Demtroeder2008, Hoffmann2007}}
  ```
- your document features a `\tableofcontents` directive near the start of the document. The arguments of the various sectioning commands -- including the citation call-out -- show up in the Table of Contents. That's the cause of the problem you're looking to fix.

To avoid this outcome, you can make use of the optional "short" version of sectioning commands and, in particular, omit the `\citep` instruction in the short version. If present, the short version is used for the table of contents. Thus, I suggest you use the following form of the `\subsection` command:

```
\subsection[Equations of motions for a charged particle in an
accelerating potential]{Equations of motions for a charged particle
in an accelerating potential~\citep{Demtroeder2008, Hoffmann2007}}
```

Observe that the short and full versions are identical except for the absence of the `\citep` directive in the short version.

After adjusting the `\subsection` directive in this manner, be sure to recompile the document (at least) twice to fully propagate all changes to the table of contents, the formatted bibliography, and the citation callouts.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I totally forgot that it appears in the TOC and that is why it is the first reference.

Now I also know about "short version of citation" which I did not know before. Very handy.